# Setting and accessing member variables in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing an open source project for the Xbox 360, it's my first time using C++ and I'm obviously doing something (Most likely many things) wrong.

My specific problem at the moment is that I create many instances of a class, passing in a reference to an object in the constructor, and setting a member variable to that object.

Later, when I access these objects, the member variable does not contain the object I assigned to it in the constructor.

Also, these objects have an Update(float x, float y) method, in this method I simply assign the x and y to member variables _x and _y.

When I access these values later, they are garbage.

I'm going to try post the relevant code here, but there may be something I miss, so just in case here is a link to the github project [Github - Xenu](https://github.com/Diggs/Xenu/).

The class I'm referring to is source/GUIApplicationPanel and the instantiating/using of them is in source/GUIManager.

Here is the object I am instantiating many instances of:

```
GUIApplicationPanel.H

class GUIApplicationPanel {
public:
    GUIApplicationPanel(LibXenonApplication libXenonApplication);
    void update(float x, float y);
    void draw();

private:
    LibXenonApplication application;
    float _x, _y;
};

GUIApplicationPanel.CPP

GUIApplicationPanel::GUIApplicationPanel(LibXenonApplication libXenonApplication) 
{
    application = libXenonApplication;
}

void GUIApplicationPanel::update(float x, float y)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

void GUIApplicationPanel::draw()
{
    Draw::DrawColoredRect(_x, _y, 0.3f, 0.3f, ThemeManager::GetPanelColor());
}
```

And here is the code that creates them:

```
GUIManager.H

class GUIManager {
public:
    void update(controller_data_s controller);

    void draw();

private:
    /* SNIP SNIP */

    vector<GUIApplicationPanel> *currentPanels;

    vector<GUIApplicationPanel> applicationPanels;
};

GUIManager.C

vector<LibXenonApplication> applications = LibXenonApplicationManager::GetApplications(applicationsPath);

// Create panels for applications
for(vector<LibXenonApplication>::iterator iter = applications.begin(); iter != applications.end(); ++iter) {
     applicationPanels.push_back(GUIApplicationPanel(*iter));
}
```

Here is the code that updates them:

```
currentPanels = &applicationPanels;

// Render each screens worth of panels
    for(int currentPass = 0; currentPass < renderPasses; currentPass++) {

        horizontalOffset = currentPass * 1.0f;

        for(int verticalPanel = 0; verticalPanel < verticalPanels; verticalPanel++) {

            for(int horizontalPanel = 0; horizontalPanel < horizontalPanels; horizontalPanel++) {

                // Make sure we haven't exceeded the amount of panels we're drawing...
                if(panelIndex >= currentPanels->size()){break;}

                // Get the panel at the current index
                GUIApplicationPanel currentPanel = currentPanels->at(panelIndex);

                // Calculate its position
                float panelX = horizontalOffset + xStart + (horizontalPanel * panelWidth) + (horizontalPanel * panelGap);
                float panelY = yStart + (verticalPanel * panelHeight) + (verticalPanel * panelGap);

                // Update the panel
                currentPanel.update(panelX, panelY);

                // Move to the next panel...
                panelIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And lastly here is the code that accesses values on them:

```
for(vector<GUIApplicationPanel>::iterator iter = currentPanels->begin(); iter != currentPanels->end(); ++iter) {
    iter->draw();
}
```

To be honest I'm all out of ideas - Acessing the application variable on a panel anywhere other than the constructor results in it being garbage, and likewise with _x and _y (Other than in the update method).

I put some logging in, so a line will be logged in the update method of the panel logging the values of _x and _y after they've been set, as well as showing the name of the application (Which comes out blank in the log).

A line will also be logged when the draw method is called showing the current values of _x, _y and application:

```
Updating  to x -0.70 y 0.40
Updating  to x -0.30 y 0.40
Updating  to x 0.10 y 0.40
Updating  to x 0.50 y 0.40
Updating  to x 0.90 y 0.40
Updating  to x -0.70 y 0.80
Updating  to x -0.30 y 0.80
Updating  to x 0.10 y 0.80
Updating  to x 0.50 y 0.80
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 275577729171396449271808.00
Drawing  at x 0.00 y 0.00
```

Comment: Your question and example code are both very long.  Please could you simplify your code to the **absolute minimum** required to exhibit the core issue?

Comment: I just cut a little bit, as I said I don't know the relevant bits of code as I wonder if the problem is the way I'm iterating through these objects, so i want to leave that code in there.

Comment: you say you pass a reference in the constructor, but I can't see this in the code. What's right: Text or code?

Comment: Sorry the code is the source of truth :) The text is my intention.

Comment: Not a real question. Why too much hand waving and speculation to make it reproducible. Concrete example of code not working is the absolute minimum requirement.With inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you access the elements in the vector:

```
GUIApplicationPanel currentPanel = currentPanels->at(panelIndex);
```

This obtains a copy of the element, so you set the attributes of the copy, not the item held in the container. Obtain a reference and then you can modify the item in the container..

EDIT: Based on comment, as you've realised `std::vector<>::at()` return a reference, so what you need to do is change the above to be a reference, i.e.

```
GUIApplicationPanel& currentPanel = currentPanels->at(panelIndex);
```

Now `currentPanel` *refers* to the instance of `GUIApplicationPanel` at the specified index in the container.

Comment: +1. Ah, that is! Great catch. I was commenting some of this indirectly, ut obviously there lays an error...

Comment: Can you please show an example of how to do this? The documentation for vector.at() is "Returns a reference to the element at position n in the vector."

Comment: Thank you very much that makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem is with initialization. `_x` and `_y` are not initialized in the constructor of `GUIApplicationPanel`, and may have arbitrary values. If, by chance, a panel is not updated, it will have that rare values.

**EDIT**:

As per your comment, another problem could be that you hold variables of type `LibXenonApplication` and `GUIapplicationPanel` *by value*. I suggest you to use pointers to hold references to those panels instead of *copies* of those objects. There may lay your errors.

Comment: I tried that by in the panel constructor saying _x = 1.0f, _y = 1.0f. But I still got the exact same values coming out in the log :/

Comment: Then, it may have to do with some fault elsewhere. For instance, you hold variables of type `LibXenonApplication` and `GUIapplicationPanel` *by value*. I suggest you to use pointers to hold references to those panels instead of *copies* of those objects. There may lay your errors.